# How to only get places having phone numbers via Foursquare api?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, foursquare

i am trying to implement forsquare api in my project to get nearby places, but i want the places with phone numbers only.

The following url is created when searching for some places:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=NUAAA4QFSP...MEW5QYULV&client_secret=FIGD...X0LQBAB&v=20131109&locale=en&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259&ll=33.85982057734948,35.55264679015678&radius=2000
```

The problem is the result will contains all the places corresponding to the categories I checked and within the radius 2000.

I tried to add "query", but this will only search in the result name 
So how to get only the places with phone numbers?

Thank you